# How can I rename the data of a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

To be specific. I have a pandas dataframe column called id, its data is 10,20,30, etc

how can I rename the column's data all the way from 1,2,3,4, etc in ascending order instead of 10,20,30?

Comment: something like `df['id'] = df['id'].div(10).astype(int)` ?